# IronPython cannot import os: ImportException: "not a Zipfile"

Tags: c#, ironpython, python-import

I am trying to execute this script from a Console .NET 4.5 application

Script: test1.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

C#: Program.cs

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     ExecuteScript();
     Console.Read();
 }

 private static void ExecuteScript()
 {
     var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
     var scope = engine.CreateScope();
     var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"D:\Scripts\test1.py");
     engine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();
     source.Execute(scope);
 }
```

If i run this, i get an IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException.
If i ignore this exception (detach VS debugger) it works, but i would like to know how to properly handle it, or if i should just ignore it?

Thanks,
Yann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of right now you can only ignore this non-fatal, internal exception or disable zip import support.

Instead of fully detaching the debugger you could enable just my code or exclude breaking on import exceptions.

To disable zip import support you can clear (or check and remove a specific handler if there are multiple) path_hooks:

```
var pc = HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(engine) as PythonContext;
var hooks = pc.SystemState.Get__dict__()["path_hooks"] as List;
hooks.Clear();
```

More information can be found in [the corresponding ticket on github](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues/1085).

Comment: Thanks! How do you disable zip import support?

Comment: I have editied my answer and added a snippet example of how to remove the zip handler.

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, i create a pull request, which will solve it. maybe it will be accpeted :)

my fix is, to make import modules stateful:

```
foreach (object hook in (IEnumerable)pathHooks) {
    try {
        object handler = PythonCalls.Call(context, hook, dirname);

        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (handler is IImporterModule)
            {
                if ((handler as IImporterModule).State == ImporterModuleState.Ready)
                {
                    return handler;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return handler;
            }
        }
    } catch (ImportException) {
        // we can't handle the path
    }
}
```

Pull request on git-hub: https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/pull/1247